# Unable to select element by model

Tags: javascript, selenium, testing, jasmine, protractor

I need to select an element by model name but it's not working, the details are given below:

The element is:

```
textarea rows="8" ng-model="panel.information_text['comment']" >
```

Our Code:

```
input_ele = element(by.model("panel.information_text[\'comment\']"));
console.log(input_ele.getText());
```

Output:

```
{ ptor_:
    { controlFlow: [Function],
    schedule: [Function],
    setFileDetector: [Function],
    getSession: [Function],
    getCapabilities: [Function],
    quit: [Function],
    actions: [Function],
    touchActions: [Function],
    executeScript: [Function],
    executeAsyncScript: [Function],
    call: [Function],
    wait: [Function],
    sleep: [Function],
    getWindowHandle: [Function],
    getAllWindowHandles: [Function],
    getPageSource: [Function],
    close: [Function],
    getCurrentUrl: [Function],
    getTitle: [Function],
    findElementInternal_: [Function],
    findDomElement_: [Function],
    findElementsInternal_: [Function],
    takeScreenshot: [Function],
    manage: [Function],
    switchTo: [Function],
    driver:
    }
}
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

You've actually located the element by model successfully.

The thing you see printed is a **promise** returned by `getText()`. If you want to see an actual text on the console, **resolve the promise** explicitly via `then()`:

```
input_ele.getText().then(function (text) {
    console.log(text);
});
```

Note that if you would want to use `expect()` to assert the element's text being equal to something, *`expect()` would implicitly resolve promises for you*, e.g. you can write:

```
expect(input_ele.getText()).toEqual("Expected text");
```

See also:

- [Understanding JavaScript Promises](https://spring.io/understanding/javascript-promises)
- [Promises and the Control Flow](https://github.com/angular/protractor/blob/master/docs/control-flow.md#promises-and-the-control-flow)